# pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: thedb.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255: [WinError 10060]

Tags: python, mongodb, azure

I have a mongodb database hosted in azure cosmos db. I'm trying to connect to it with python/cosmosdb compass but i got time out error.

I know that my code is clean as it was tested by another developer (on his laptop).

The error :

```
Generated by python code
 `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: thedb.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255: [WinError 10060] Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou un
e connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 60000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 60000.0ms), Timeout: 60.0s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 655e1519766d498a
8bbc7059, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('thedb.mongo.cosmos.azure.com', 10255) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('thedb.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255: [WinError 10060] U
ne tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS
: 60000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 60000.0ms)')>]>

Mongodb compass 
connect ETIMEDOUT 20.61.97.0:10255
```

Comment: Please edit to provide more detail (a [mcve]). This including code (whether you think it's clean or not, nobody here can see it currently). Also: it's important to tag correctly - are you connecting to a MongoDB API instance of Cosmos DB? A Cosmos DB MongoDB vCore deployment? And what about your connection string? Without sharing real credentials (e.g. the username and key) you should share the connection string, along with other relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

**TimeoutError** is related to connection

1. Is your **ip** address added to the firewall to allow it through ?
2. Check if `Server Side Retry` is `Enabled`.
3. Also, if your colleague is able to access then you can ask your IT department to mimic their access to your access?

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer - it's troubleshooting tips. And the OP has shared no detail aside from an error message.

Comment: Hello,   Thanks it was "Is your ip address added to the firewall to allow it through ?"

Comment: @maa3301 also if you find the answer useful you can ✔️ so that other fellow stack members know if he find same doubt as yours.